# pass list of Pair to myBatis

Tags: mybatis

I need to  a list of Pair to MyBatis query:

in Mapper:

```
List<Usage> getUsageByUserLanguagesAndDates(
      @Param("userLanguagePairList") List<Pair<String, String>> userLanguageMap,
      @Param("startDate") DateTime startDate,
      @Param("endDate") DateTime endDate)
```

List> userLanguageMap looks like this:

```
List<Pair<String, String>> pairs = Lists.newArrayList;
pairs.add(new Pair("12345", "en-US"));
pairs.add(new Pair("23456", "en-GB"));
...
```

and the query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    ...
    FROM
    ...
    WHERE 1=1
    AND 
    (
        (l.userid = '12345' AND ll.language_code = 'en-US') OR
        (l.userid = '23456' AND ll.language_code = 'en-GB') 
    )
   ;
```

I tried to write the query as:

```
AND (
    <foreach item="userLanguagePair" index="index" collection="userLanguagePairList" open="" separator="," close="">
      (
        l.userid = #{userLanguagePair.first}
        AND
        ll.language_code = #{userLanguagePair.second}
      )
      OR
    </foreach>
    )
```

...

but there will be an extra OR at the end:

```
AND 
        (
            (l.userid = '12345' AND ll.language_code = 'en-US') OR
            (l.userid = '23456' AND ll.language_code = 'en-US') OR
        )
```

how can i get rid of the last 'OR'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html:

`<foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list" open="(" separator="," close=")">`,

so I'd say your code should be something like this:

```
...
WHERE 1=1 AND (
<foreach item="userLanguagePair" index="index" collection="userLanguagePairList" open="(" separator="OR" close=")">
    l.userid = #{userLanguagePair.first}
    AND
    ll.language_code = #{userLanguagePair.second}
</foreach>
)
```

but right now I cannot check if this will generate the correct sentence.

Comment: I ended up with this:   <foreach item="userLanguagePair" index="index" collection="userLanguagePairList" open="(" separator=") OR (" close=")">